# How to check if the value of the key "x" is equal to "value-any"?

Tags: python, json, if-statement, conditional-statements

Follow my example:

I have a JSON file
Whose "license" key is equal to "valid"
Ex:

```
{
license: "valid", 
email: "joaodascoves@gmail.com",
site: "google.com"
}
```

How do I create a conditional:

> if the key value "license" is equal to "valid"

I return an X command, if it is **"invalid" I return the command "y"**

I need this, because I want to create a licensing system that will analyze the JSON by URL, and check if the key "license" returns as "valid" or "invalid" and thus execute the different commands depending on these two conditions.

Comment: I think you just need to load the json to variable example variable var, then make if statement that checks if var["license"] == "valid"

Comment: Hello, I tried to do it this way, but it is giving error: TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable

Comment: can you add a picture how you do it and the error message?

Comment: Even better you should add the code you already have!

Answer (score 2):

Convert it to a dict with `dict=json.loads("{ license: "valid",  email: "joaodascoves@gmail.com", site: "google.com" })`
or put the file data in the string
then do something like

```
if dict["licence"]=="valid":
     return True
```

dont forget to `import json`